# Make loop for a list of multiple list

Tags: python, loops

I want to make a loop of a list of multiple list, I have something like this:

```
my_list = [ [ [1,2], [2,3] ], [ [2,3], [2,3] ], [ [1,2], [1,3] ] ]
```

So, I want to keep only the first value if the second is greater than the first one, I don't want second value in the output, and here is my script:

```
new_list = []
for member in range(0, len(my_list)):
    for m,n in my_list[member]:
        if m.distance < n.distance
            new_list.append([m])
```

when I run it, it removes one level of the list and returns this:

```
new_list = [[1], [2], [2], [2], [1], [1]]
```

What is missing?
This is what I expect from output:

```
new_list = [ [ [1],[2] ], [ [2],[2] ], [ [1],[1] ] ]
```

Comment: Can you please provide the exact output you expect please

Comment: Use `new_list.append([m, n])` instead of `new_list.append([m])`.  The second number isn't there because you never added it.

Comment: Is the same output with new_list.append([m, n])

Comment: what do you expect when the second element is not greater than the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [map()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) functional primitive here to easily express the result.

I assume that all inner lists have at least 2 elements and if the second element is not greater than the first one, then the whole list is returned rather than only its first element.

```
>>> my_list = [ [ [1,2], [2,3] ], [ [2,3], [2,3] ], [ [1,2], [1,3] ] ]
>>> map(lambda x: map(lambda y: y[:1] if y[1] > y[0] else y, x), my_list)
[[[1], [2]], [[2], [2]], [[1], [1]]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You need to add a sublist as below:

```
new_list =[]
for l in my_list:
  sub_list=[]
  for m, n in l:
      if m<n:
          sub_list.append(m)
new_list.append(sub_list)

>>>[[1, 2], [2, 2], [1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work assuming that you want to keep the second value if that's lower, you don't specify that case in your question:

```
[[[min(x)] for x in y] for y in my_list]
```